# How to Dependency Swap using Simple Injector in ASP.NET Core 3.1 for Integration Tests

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, integration-testing, simple-injector

I'm struggling with setting up DI using SimpleInjector (4.9) in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 application for my Integration Tests, so that I can dependency swap out target configured services that are registered in the Startup class as per standard ASP.NET Core startup configuration.

What I want to achieve is basically something like this:

1. Use Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer (or equivalent) to "host" the test
2. Initialize Startup as "normal", so there's no need to maintain separate IoCs for testing and runtime
3. Swap out/override key dependencies with mocks, like API calls to external services and RabbitMQ
4. Run tests using Startup config with mocks

My problem is that I can't seem to find a way to interact with the SI Container to have it override the dependencies, similar to how [Adam Storr solved it](https://adamstorr.azurewebsites.net/blog/integration-testing-with-aspnetcore-3-1-swapping-dependency). I've tried to gather inspiration from the guides posted by Adam Storr, Andrew Lock, Gunnar Peipman, and of course the official docs, but no matter how I try and combine the solutions with SimpleInjector there's always something critical that doesn't work.

I can't access the Container created within Startup and have it change the dependencies, since Startup is generated by .UseStartup, and even then it would mean exposing the Startup class in some convoluted way. I also can't inject a Container into Startup since [that's not supported anymore](https://andrewlock.net/avoiding-startup-service-injection-in-asp-net-core-3/).

But if I try to create a subclass of Startup and use that I end up with the issue that the Controllers can't be found by default and so the Http(Test)Client returns 404's. And if I try to resolve this as per [Gunnar Peipman's suggestion](https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-integration-test-startup/) SimpleInjector fails with a:

`System.InvalidOperationException : For the SimpleInjectorControllerActivator to function properly, it requires all controllers to be registered explicitly in Simple Injector, but a registration for WeatherForecastController is missing. To ensure all controllers are registered properly, call the RegisterMvcControllers extension method on the Container from within your Startup.Configure method while supplying the IApplicationBuilder instance, e.g. "this.container.RegisterMvcControllers(app);"`

(Which isn't even an up-to-date way to solve it since RegisterMvcControllers(app) is deprecated in favor of AddControllerActivation - [ref](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html))

I've uploaded a sample repo [here](https://github.com/sawujul/SimpleInjectorIntegrationTest) that shows the issue(s); some guidance here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does it mean to "Initialize Startup as 'normal', so there's no need to maintain separate IoCs for testing and runtime"?

Comment: Have you looked at the [How To - Override Existing Registrations](https://simpleinjector.org/howto#override-existing-registrations) documentation section? Does that help?

Comment: Btw, thank you for reporting the issue wit h`RegisterMvcControllers` in the exception message. I created [an issue](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/802) for this and it will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: @Steven What I mean is that I've seen some suggest to maintain a completely separate Startup replica that has the changes you want, like a "MockStartup", except that every time you made a change to Startup you'd have to make the same relative change in MockStartup. I'd very much like to avoid that, as I've seen before how corrupted the replica can get over time.

Comment: @Steven I've reviewed the override section, and if you see my repo you can see that I've used just that to allow overriding the dependency, but my problem is that I have nowhere to place this override that isn't inside the Startup.cs, which means it would contain test logic. My struggle remains with finding out how to have my test use Startup.cs and make the override without exposing Startup to test logic.

Answer (score 4):

After further digging, I found the issue that prevented all my attempts at working: In order to have your integration test register the controllers you have to change the test project SDK from:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

To:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

And fair enough, it does say so under the [prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#test-app-prerequisites), but to be honest I think it's beyond strange that the test project templates don't come with this already configured, or that there isn't a specific template for this - very common - scenario, or that none of the guides I've found mention this critical piece of configuration. It's very easy to miss if you trust in the templates.

With this fixed, it's now quite simple to use a subclass of Startup with mocked overrides using SimpleInjector.