# How to swap dependencies in Simple Injector for Integration Testing when conditional registrations exist

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1, simple-injector, .net-core-3.1, .net-4.8

We are setting up integration tests and would like to be able to swap out some real implementations for stubs. It seems possible when looking at [How to Dependency Swap using Simple Injector in ASP.NET Core 3.1 for Integration Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60379940/how-to-dependency-swap-using-simple-injector-in-asp-net-core-3-1-for-integration), but we also have conditional registrations.

The setting `container.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations = true;` does not work in combination with conditional registrations.

Is there a work around?

To clarify: the registrations that we would want to override are preferably not conditional, but having any conditional registrations disallows the setting `container.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations` to be `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're witnessing is a limitation in Simple Injector <= 5.0.3. It disallows conditionals to be registered when `AllowOverridingRegistrations` is set to `true`, even when there are no existing registrations for that particular service type.

This limitation has (now) been lifted in 5.0.4. In this version, it will still be impossible to replace or add a conditional registration for an already registered service type, but adding a conditional registration for a completely new service type is now possible.

Comment: Yes, that would work, but there is a bigger issue at hand here: `AllowOverridingRegistrations` cannot even be set to `true` IF there are any conditional registrations. Even if I were not to override any of these, then still the exception pops up just because some registrations are conditional.

Comment: That's not how `AllowOverridingRegistrations` is set up to work. Perhaps you are hitting a bug (in an old version), but I just verified with 5.0.3 and it is possible to override (non-conditional) registrations with `AllowOverridingRegistrations`, even if there are conditional ones (for unrelated abstractions).

Comment: This project uses `SimpleInjector 4.10.2`. We are not quite ready to switch to 5.0 there. I will investigate further tomorrow.

Comment: I just tested this with versions 4.10.2, 4.9.2, 4.8.1, and 4.7.1 and they all seem to work. It might be you're hitting a corner case, or having a different use case then I'm testing on. If you have a repro, you can post it to GitHub. I'm very much interested to see it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get around to it today. I will keep you posted!

Comment: The problem occurred because I set `AllowOverridingRegistrations = true` right at the beginning, before adding any registrations. If I first add all my registrations, and then set this option to true, verification succeeds.

Comment: The latter is the advised practice, because this helps S.I. guard accidental duplicate registrations.

Comment: I'm still wondering why the exception occurs though. As we don't override any registrations, it should not matter wether we set the option beforehand or afterwards. I will try to find out which registrations cause the exception and make a repro.

Comment: You could argue that the reporting can be improved to only throw when overriding would take place. I decided to keep the checking "dumb" because it's easy to turn off overriding and having a a mechanism that is "too smart" can lead to confusion of its own with the user.

Comment: Right. Fair enough ;-)

Comment: The behavior has been modified as of Simple Injector 5.0.4: registration of conditionals is now allowed under specific circumstances. See https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/850